# Waypoint Navigation: Simplified Local Planner

Tags: ros, navigation, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering if anyone has written such a behaviour for a robot navigation or any hint on how to implement it.

1- The robot gets the waypoints from the global planner
2- Starting from the first waypoint, the robot rotates towards the next waypoint
3- The Robot moves on a straight line and stops at the next waypoint
4- The robot rotates towards the next waypoint
5- The Robot moves on a straight line and stops at the next waypoint
6- Goto 4

Assuming that there is enough distance between the waypoints.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196854/waypoint-navigation:-simplified-local-planner/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nazeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21555/nazeer/) on 2015-03-03**:
Am looking for same as you asked, did you find the answer yet?
Can you let me know if you knew something about it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a version of this idea that works, but currently does no collision detection.
https://github.com/DLu/simple_local_planner

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1